# In ExpressJS, Navigation bar collapse is not working in responsive mode

Tags: css, express

I am using jade in ExpressJS application. The collapsed button on the right corner is visible in responsive mode but Its navigation heads not getting displayed. 
I have attached my code. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
body
    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
      .container
        .navbar-header
          a.navbar-brand(href='/') MyBlogs
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse',data-target='#navbar-main' aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar-main')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
        #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
            ul.nav.navbar-nav
              li
                a(href='#about') About
              li
                a(href='#ADF') ADF
              li
                a(href='#SOA') SOA
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: yes , I am using bootstrap3.3.7 .